# tabBar keeps sliderView from working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uislider

I have an application that uses a tableView and a tabBar. When one of the view controllers (`NOTabBarView`) is loaded from the tableView I hide the tabBar by putting:

```
[self.tabBarController.TabBar setHidden:YES];
```

in `viewWillAppear`
and I make it visible in the `viewWillDisappear` using:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
```

In the `NOTabBarView` there is a slider that is in the area that the tabBar is.

When I hide the tabBar I can see the slider but I cannot interact with it.
If I move it out of the area of the tabBar then I can interact with the tabBar.

Is there a way to get the slider to work while in the area of the tabBar?
I have tried moving the tabBar out of the way with:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake:(0,900,480,50);
```

but that doesn't seem to let me interact with the slider.
I have also tried placing the slider at the front of the view

```
[self.view insertSubview:slider atIndex:100];
```

but this does't work either.

Any ideas on how to get the slider to work when in the tabBar space?

Comment: Are you using `Push`while moving to `NonTabBarView`?

Comment: Please check you might be pushing tabBar while you are inside the tabBar .

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by using

```
self.tarBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake:(355,520,350,1);
```

in the viewWillAppear and then

```
self.tarBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake:(0,520,350,49);
```

in viewWillDisappear

somehow this moves it out of the way and makes it small enough it doesn't effect
the sliderViews